# Can I use a past simple and a past perfect in the same sentence? If so, what logic does it follow?

Tags: grammaticality, perfect-constructions

> "I didn't consider the possibility of someone asking me a question after I had crossed them off my list."

Or,

> "I didn't consider the possibility of someone asking me a question after I crossed them off my list."

Which sentence is grammatically correct, and why?

Comment: After I had crossed them off my list.  It helps if you draw yourself a timeline.

Comment: Both are correct. You start with the verb in the main clause "did consider" which is as you say past tense, and then consider three options: do you want to show another completed past action in the dependent clause? An earlier action? or state a general truth? Your first sentence is correct and shows an earlier action. The second is correct also, but now you show another completed past action. It's up to you which sentence you want to use. Source: http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/sequence.htm

Answer (score 1):

> Can I use a past simple and a past perfect in the same sentence? If so, what logic does it follow?

Past-perfect leaves an "opening" between the time the event occurred and now, for some other past event to happen to "fill in".  Sometimes this other event is not expressed because context provides it or the speaker/writer is referencing something disconnected to "now."

This can always be done "manually" with time-relation words, so many times it's redundant, but needed if you don't want to sound unnatural.

If you specify this other past event, simple past is used.

> I didn't consider the possibility of someone asking me a question after I had crossed them off my list

"Had crossed off my list" - Opening exists for another event to happen before "now", which is "possibility of someone asking me  a question"

> Q: When did he talk to you?
>
> A: After I had crossed him off my list.

Same concept here, but A does not explicitly state the event, because "he talked to me" is implied from context created by the question.